# Simple instructions for how to get this particular lighting for a headshot?

Tags: lighting, headshot

Particularly referring to the shadow under the chin. The cheeks look really sharp as well, I know the person imaged has low body fat but I'm sure there's lighting tips for that as well.

As well, would anyone be able to (roughly) estimate the distance from subject to camera, and focal length, that might have been used?

[image]

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: What do the catchlights reflected in the subject's eyes tell you about the lighting?

Comment: The catch lights are almost perfectly circular...he's being lit by the moon and this photo was taken right before his werewolf transformation. Do be careful photographing the 'wolves, they spook easy and aren't known for their pleasantries.

Comment: Looks like a flash on a bracket attached to the camera positioned as Olin said.  Most people do not want this lighting because it looks terrible.

Answer (score 3):

There was one strong light a bit above and slightly to the right of the camera, from the photographer's point of view behind the camera.  There was additional diffuse light around.

If the camera was maybe 4 feet from the subject, then the key light was maybe a foot above the camera and maybe 3 inches to the right.

Answer (score 3):

Main light above the camera. Something on the background, to soften the shadow.

You might find this interesting.  Your pic is an extreme version of the 4th example.

https://digital-photography-school.com/6-portrait-lighting-patterns-every-photographer-should-know/